# How to get content without nested elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nested, nokogiri

```
src = '<paragraph>And bla foo <note>not important</note> bar baz</paragraph>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(src)
puts doc.xpath('paragraph').first.content
```

The code above returns:

```
"And bla foo not important bar baz"
```

I am looking for a way to get content without nested elements.
The case above is just an example XML, but in this example I want this as a result:

```
"And bla foo bar baz"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
puts doc.xpath('paragraph/child::text()')
```

I've not used XPath in anger for many years but that seems to work.

Or better yet:

```
puts doc.xpath('paragraph/child::text()').to_s.squeeze(' ')
```

Comment: squeeze reduces the string to 'And bla fo bar baz' - it reduces the o's :-) You should add squeeze(' ') instead

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
doc.xpath('paragraph').children.map { |e| e.text if e.text? }.join
```

That will return 'And bla foo  bar baz' from your example

Comment: This will walk every node in the XML DOM inspecting them to see if they are text nodes. It would be better to ask for only the `text()` nodes. That could be a huge savings in a big document.